# "Close the light" — regionalism or mere oddity?

Tags: verbs, dialects, non-native-english

If I want the room in darkness, and wish to announce my intent, I would say

> I'm going to turn off the light.

But occasionally here in America I hear people say

> I'm going to close the light.

It's happened too often to chalk up to mistake or happenstance. I'm just wondering if anyone knows if this is a regional usage and, if so, what region?

Comment: I've heard "close the light" from non-native speakers from Israel and also from Europe but I can't recall which countries specifically. I think it's a translationism.

Comment: It could originate from Chinese also. In Chinese, *open* and *turn on* are the same word, as well as *close* and *turn off*. So people whose first language is Chinese are likely to say *open/close the light*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this from Wikipedia's entry for Canadian English in the section on [Quebec's regionalisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English#Quebec):

> It is also common for Anglophones to use translated French words instead of common English equivalents, such as "open" and "close" for "on" and "off", e.g. "Open the lights, please" for "Turn on the lights, please".

And then this from [Yahoo Answers (Canada)](http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070606062135AAnJhAf):

> Q: Is the saying "close the light" proper english?
>   Just wondering.
>
> A: I teach English in Quebec and I hear it ALL THE TIME!!!
>   It's a translation problem. This happens with French and Italian. -maybe other languages too.
>
> [and further down]
>
> A: Well Im Aussie and some of us say "close the light" as well so dont be too worried about it will you. There are those who will correct you but I think it really depends which school you went to and how your mum and dad said it.

There's also an interesting discussion on this at [Ask Metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/9204/Regional-Linguistics) that seems to confirm the "Franglicism" theory.

Comment: In Italian, the correct way of saying it is _spegni la luce_, which the translation of _turn off the light_. _Chiudi la luce_, the translation of _close the light_ is a regionalism, and not standard Italian.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The same is true in French - standard French has *allumer/éteindre la lumière*, and while some people do say *ouvrir/fermer* it [isn't considered 100% standard](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080825035817AABgLYQ).

Comment: I know many native Russian speakers who say "close the light", however, the Russian equivalent is "выключить свет" meaning "turn off the light"; I am not aware of any Russian regionalism that uses "close".  Perhaps it also is attributable to the fact that the word "close" is a simple, single verb, whereas "turn off" is a more complex word sequence?

Comment: It's translation. In French, you say *fermer la lumière*, in Italian *chiudere la luce*. I grew up in an Italian family and Italian neighbourhood, and though we only ever spoke English, I grew up saying "close the lights". It wasn't till my twenties when I moved to another area that people started telling me it was improper English. However, I've never been able to break the habit.

Comment: @user24655 In both French and Italian, there is an equivalent to turn on/off (allumer/éteindre, accendere/spegnere). You might say _fermer_ or _chiudere_, but you would be making a mistake :-)

Comment: In Indonesia, we say (tolong) matikan/nyalakan lampunya which means (please) turn off/turn on the light  - only in some region (usually in Sumatra or remote region from big city) that says: (tolong) tutup/buka lampunya which means (please) close/open the light. It sounds really weird though.. to open/close the light...

Answer (score 7):

*Open the light...close the light* is considered a New Jersey-ism. I grew up in Hillsdale, New Jersey, a comfortable suburb of NYC, and learned from my parents to say *open/close the light.*

When I was 10 years old we moved to Upstate New York (only a little more than an hour north). People looked at me like I had three heads when I would say *open/close the light.* I noticed that people up there would say *turn on/ turn off the light*. As an adult I lived in NYC, and I never heard anyone say *open/close the light*, so as far as I know, it is a Jersey thing.

Comment: I've lived in New Jersey my whole life and know many people from all over the state and I have only just recently heard this phrase. I would not say this is a New Jersey thing.

Comment: I grew up in New Jersey and my girlfriend who grew up in Illinois was constantly making fun of me for saying "close the light", so it seems there's some truth to the New Jersey-ism thing.

Answer (score 4):

Is it perhaps a carryover from gas lights (before electricity)? Back then, to make it dark, you had to "turn off" or "close" the gas valve.

Comment: Could be, who knows? Or there was perhaps some kind of blind to cover the window in an oil lamp through which the light would shine?

Answer (score 3):

Here in California it's associated with a pidgin-Hawaiian. "Pio the light" somehow morphed into "close the light." And, weirdly enough, seems to have traveled around. My older sister, who has never been to Hawaii, uses it. No one else in the family does.

Not to inject too many family drama into the discussion, but I've always associated the phrase with the proudly under-educated sort.

Answer (score 3):

I've said "open the light" and "close the light" my whole life (I am now 61 years old).  I was born and grew up in the Bronx to American-born parents.  The only thing I can figure out is that perhaps my grandmother, who was born in New York City on the Lower East Side to Yiddish-speaking parents, said this and I picked it up from her.  We definitely had no native-born French speakers in our family, so I always figured it was from the Yiddish translation.  I am certainly not under-educated.

Answer (score 1):

My father, who was raised in New Hampshire by nonimmigrant-Italian parents from NYC, occasionally uses "close the light". (I don't recall him saying "open the light".) This might corroborate a NJ(/NYC) regionalism, or possibly a correlated Italian community one.

Answer (score 0):

I am Chinese; however, I have been educated by British English teachers all my life. I never say *open/close*, although the fact that saying *open or close the light* is wrong was drilled into me.